# How to convert this Python code into Java?

Tags: java, python, base64, hmacsha1

I wish to convert following python code into Java. This code encodes credit card data using hash algorithms and keys. I have written some Java code based on my understanding below that. I think mainly its about panmackey. I am not sure how to generate its value for Java.

Python Code:

```
panmackey   = bytes.fromhex('449E5A196233A43819A028770880E814DC420BFFC428295787302E6285FDD685')

def pandgstsha(track2, pan_mac_key=panmackey):

                h = hmac.HMAC(pan_mac_key, hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
                h.  (bytes(track2.split('=')[0]+track2.split('=')[1][:4],'UTF-8'))
                return base64.b64encode(h.finalize())
```

Java code:

```
String tokenPan = ccNum + expiryStr;
String panmackey= "?????????????????????";//pan_mac_key from python code
Mac  mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");
byte[]  decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(panmackey.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec(decodedBytes, mac.getAlgorithm());
mac.init(sk);
byte[] resultBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(tokenPan.getBytes("ASCII")));
String sB64 = new String(resultBase64, "UTF-8");
```

I need to figure out panmackey and if the 2 codes do exactly same function.

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: updated my question, should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
...
byte[] panmackey= Hex.decodeHex("Hex string goes here");
```

Otherwise, you'll have to implement your own conversion function like this;

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
    byte[] decoded = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      int index = i * 2;
      int value = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
      decoded[i] = (byte) value;
    }
    return decoded;
  }
```

Comment: For the Hex string '449E5A196233A43819A028770880E814DC420BFFC428295787302E6285FDD685' it generated '[B@372f7a8d' and '[B@2f92e0f4' using the 2 solutions you have proposed. Why 2 different outputs? Can you please help?

Comment: That's the ID of the object, not the value stored in the it.
[B indicates the object is of type byte
[B@ is "Byte array at ID xxxxxxxx", so yes, each one will have it's own ID... Because they're not the same object.

If you want to print the contents to the console, you'll have to convert the byte[] back to a string.

You could use Hex.encodeHexString(panmackey) to verify, but all you're doing is converting from a hex string to a byte array and then back to the exact same hex string you started with...

Comment: hm, not sure why its nor generating output same as python code.